# org.springframework.aop.AopInvocationException: Null return value from advice does not match primitive return type for: public abstract char

Tags: java, jpa

I have a table defined with column char and the repo I have defined a 
query to return that column. Now when the data in the db table is null 
for the specific condition its giving me the error:

```
org.springframework.aop.AopInvocationException: Null return value from 
advice does not match primitive return type for: public abstract char
```

Below is the code snippet:

```
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
    import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

    import com.marriott.sup.beans.StepWorkflow;

    public interface flowRepo extends JpaRepository<StepWorkflow, Long> {

        @Query(
                value = "SELECT s.status FROM flow s WHERE s.XREFID 
     = :xrefId order by "
                + "s.Datestarted desc limit 1",
                nativeQuery = true)
        public char findLatestSts(@Param("xrefId") Long xrefId);

    }

    public class flowService {

        public static char INPROGRESS = 'P';
        public static char SUCCESS = 'S';
        public static char ERROR = 'E';
        public static char NOTSTARTED = 'N';

        @Autowired
        private flowRepo Fl;

        /*some basic code in between and then i am trying to call the 
      function 
      defined in repo and assign it to a character variable
    */

    Sts = Fl.findLatestSts(xrefId);
    }
```

I need this to not throw the error and instead assign some default value in case null.  Need help to fix the issue on how can I handle this.

```
org.springframework.aop.AopInvocationException: Null return value from advice does not match primitive return type for: public abstract char org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:226) at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy108.findLatestSts(Unknown Source) at com.marriott.sup.service.StepWorkflowService.getserverStepstatus(StepWorkflowService.java:79) at com.marriott.sup.web.SampleRestController.getServerStepStatus(SampleRestController.java:91) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189) at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the return type of the method in your `flowRepo` interface to `Character`?  `char` is a primitive, and consequently `null` is _not_ a valid value for it.  `Character` is the respective wrapper class which _is_ a non-primitive `Object`, so `null` is fine there.

Comment: Hi, I tried it just now and getting the null pointer exception now if (Character.toStringFl.findLatestSts(xrefId)) == null)
     {
       stepSts = 'N';
     }
     else
     {
      stepSts = Fl.findLatestSts(xrefId);
     }  2019-06-07 15:23:24.808 ERROR 205008 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null

Answer (score 20):

Try to use `Character` instead of `char`. There is situation when your query return NULL and as you know primitive types in Java can not save Null inside. So, use Object of that type like `int -> Integer, float -> Float, char -> Character`.

Or, If you really need to work with primitive, put your method inside try-catch block, to handle that issue.

Comment: @Daya I think, that answer is a Answer of a question. Maybe should accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you used the correct name for the repository, in my case I needed to fetch a user by email:

Wrong:
[image]

Corret:
[image]

**JPA could not interpret the boolean query using "find" but using "exists"**