# How to Check Email and Password Spring Boot Api

Tags: spring, spring-boot

i am beginner of spring boot framework.i have done the Spring Registation successfully.after done the stuff i made the login form api but i check through the request on postman i got the error was.what i tried so far i attached below. if the email and password correct get the message login success other wise fail

**i attached the stacktrace below**

```
org.springframework.aop.AopInvocationException: Null return value from advice does not match primitive return type for: public abstract boolean com.example.Registation.Repo.EmployeeRepo.findOneByEmailAndPassword(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:229) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.findOneByEmailAndPassword(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.Registation.Service.impl.EmployeeIMPL.loginEmployee(EmployeeIMPL.java:44) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.Registation.EmployeeController.EmployeeController.loginEmployee(EmployeeController.java:30) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1071) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:964) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:696) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_202]
```

**LoginController**

```
@PostMapping(path = "/login")
public String loginEmployee(@RequestBody LoginDTO loginDTO)
{
    String email = employeeService.loginEmployee(loginDTO);
    return email;
}
```

**Entity**

```
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @Column(name="employee_id", length = 45)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int employeeid;

    @Column(name="employee_name", length = 255)
    private String employeename;

    @Column(name="email", length = 255)
    private String email;

    @Column(name="password", length = 255)
    private String password;


    public Employee() {
    }

    public Employee(int employeeid, String employeename, String email, String password) {
        this.employeeid = employeeid;
        this.employeename = employeename;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }


    public int getEmployeeid() {
        return employeeid;
    }

    public void setEmployeeid(int employeeid) {
        this.employeeid = employeeid;
    }

    public String getEmployeename() {
        return employeename;
    }

    public void setEmployeename(String employeename) {
        this.employeename = employeename;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee{" +
                "employeeid=" + employeeid +
                ", employeename='" + employeename + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
```

**LoginDTO**

```
public class LoginDTO {
    private String email;
    private String password;

    public LoginDTO() {
    }

    public LoginDTO(String email, String password) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "LoginDTO{" +
                "email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**EmployeeRepo**

```
@EnableJpaRepositories
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepo extends JpaRepository<Employee,Integer> {
      public boolean findOneByEmailAndPassword(String email, String password);
      
}
```

**EmployeeService**

```
public interface EmployeeService {
  
    String loginEmployee(LoginDTO loginDTO);
}
```

**EmployeeIMPL**

```
@Override
public String loginEmployee(LoginDTO loginDTO) {
 if(employeeRepo.findOneByEmailAndPassword(loginDTO.getEmail(),loginDTO.getPassword()))
 {
     return "Login Success";
 }
 else
 {
     return "Login Fail";
 }

}
```

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/a/59388476/1056042 may help you

Comment: In EmployeeRepo class. Please change return type boolean to Employee.

Comment: public boolean findOneByEmailAndPassword(String email, String password);  here i changed but same error

Comment: org.springframework.aop.AopInvocationException: Null return value from advice does not match primitive return type for: public abstract boolean com.example.Registation.Repo.EmployeeRepo.findOneByEmailAndPassword(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)

Comment: EmployeeRepo class. how to change return type boolean

Comment: public boolean findOneByEmailAndPassword(String email, String password); ->  public Employee findOneByEmailAndPassword(String email, String password);

Comment: if i changed as you requested i got the error message on EmployeeIMPL if(employeeRepo.findOneByEmailAndPassword(loginDTO.getEmail(),loginDTO.getPassword()))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if the row exists, you can use "existsBy". This returns a boolean value which you could check in your if.

If you use "findOne" you get the row from the database (or null). If you do not need the data from the row, you better use exists. If you need it - store it in a variable and check if it's null.

Example with existsBy:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepo extends JpaRepository<Employee,Integer> {
  boolean existsByEmailAndPassword(String email, String password); 
}

EmployeeIMPL:

@Override
public String loginEmployee(LoginDTO loginDTO) {
  if (employeeRepo.existsByEmailAndPassword(loginDTO.getEmail(), loginDTO.getPassword())) {
    return "Login Success";
  } else {
    return "Login Fail";
  }
}
```

Example with findBy:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepo extends JpaRepository<Employee,Integer> {
  Employee findOneByEmailAndPassword(String email, String password);
}

EmployeeIMPL:

@Override
public String loginEmployee(LoginDTO loginDTO) {
  Employee employee = employeeRepo.findOneByEmailAndPassword(loginDTO.getEmail(), loginDTO.getPassword());
  if (employee != null) {
    return "Login Success for " + employee;
  } else {
    return "Login Fail";
  }
}
```

With findOne you could also use Optionals.

```
@EnableJpaRepositories
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepo extends JpaRepository<Employee,Integer> {
  Optional<Employee> findOneByEmailAndPassword(String email, String password);
}

EmployeeIMPL:

@Override
public String loginEmployee(LoginDTO loginDTO) {
  Optional<Employee> employee = employeeRepo.findOneByEmailAndPassword(loginDTO.getEmail(), loginDTO.getPassword());
  if (employee.isPresent()) {
    return "Login Success for " + employee.get();
  } else {
    return "Login Fail";
  }
}
```